# Referencing a pointer inside an object

Tags: c++, directx

I asked a question similar to this awhile ago which answered my question perfectly, but I have a new dilemma which I don't fully understand and would appreciate it if someone could help. I have the following variable in a class:

```
ID3D11Buffer* variable
```

I need to de-reference this variable in my draw call for DirectX so I create a function to do so:

```
const ID3D11Buffer* GetBuffer() const { return &variable; }
```

But then I get this error which I don't really understand and it's kinda hard to google:

error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'ID3D11Buffer *const *' to 'const ID3D11Buffer *'

Could a wise C++ guru enlighten me please? :D

**Edit: With the answer provided I get a new error, this was why I was trying to add the & at the start, how would I make this line valid?**

The draw call line:

```
md3dImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, cube.GetBuffer(), &stride, &offset);
```

The answer below creates this new error:

error C2664: 'ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const ID3D11Buffer *' to 'ID3D11Buffer *const *'

The original code I had to make this work was

```
md3dImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &buffer, &stride, &offset);
```

**Edit # 2: Thanks for the help, your suggestion made the get function valid, but the IASetVertexBuffers function still didn't like it. It returns this error with the new suggestion:**

error C2664: 'ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const ID3D11Buffer *const *' to 'ID3D11Buffer *const *'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetBuffer` should return a pointer to the buffer - not a pointer (to pointer) to it. Since `variable` is already defined as a pointer, you can simply return that:

```
const ID3D11Buffer* GetBuffer() const { return variable; }
```

`&variable` is of type `ID3D11Buffer**` which doesn't match a pointer of type `ID3D11Buffer*`, hence the error.

Edit -

After reading the edit made to the OP's post, it is clear that `GetBuffer` is supposed to return a pointer (to pointer) to the buffer. So what was in fact wrong was the *return type*, not the return value. So he simply needs to change the return type signature to:

```
const ID3D11Buffer* const* GetBuffer const { return &variable; }
//                ^^^^^^^^
```

and return what he originally did, which was the address of the pointer `variable`.

Comment: Thanks but that creates a new error, I've updated my post with the details :)

Comment: @user1157885 I was under the impression that your return value was wrong, when in fact it was the *return type* that was wrong - change your return type to `const X* const*` and return `&variable`.

Comment: Hmm thanks, it made the function valid but the DirectX draw call still didn't quite like it. I've updated my post with the new error :(

Comment: @user1157885 Now, the error that just came up wasn't a problem with what *I* did, but with the code that you already gave me. I'm going to assume the the third parameter of that function takes a non-const pointer to pointer; therefore passing in a const pointer won't work because a const to non-const conversion isn't performed by the compiler. You need to either remove the first `const` from the return type of the 3rd parameter or change the return type of `GetBuffer` to `X* const*` instead of `const X* const*`.

Answer (score 1):

`variable` is already of the type `ID3D11Buffer*`. So returning `return variable;` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

look at `const X * const`

If you draw a line at the `*`

The const on the left refers to the pointer, so you can't change the pointer value (where it points)

the const on the right refers to the object being pointed to, so you can't change the contents

Answer (score 0):

A little trick to find out which is const (pointer or variable) you can read it backwards.

- const type* X; -> Pointer to a variable of type 'type' which is const (the data is const)
- type * const X; -> const pointer to a variable of type 'type' (the pointer is const)
- const type * const X; -> const pointer to a variable of type 'type' which is const (data and pointer are const)